# Multiple JSON data

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I checked every stack overflow solution for it. On ajax request PHP return JSON data but it has multiple JSON data.

```
var json = '[{"key":"amazon"},{"key":"a a"},{"key":"a and w"},{"key":"a aa"},{"key":"a and e"},{"key":"a aa movie"},{"key":"a aa songs"},{"key":"a aa telugu movie"},{"key":"a aa full movie"},{"key":"a and f"}][{"key":"a beautiful mind"},{"key":"a boogie"},{"key":"a bigger splash"},{"key":"a bronx tale"},{"key":"a brief history of time"},{"key":"a bola"},{"key":"a bugs life"},{"key":"a bientot"},{"key":"a bathing ape"},{"key":"a beautiful mess"}]';

          console.log(JSON.parse(json));

          $.each(JSON.parse(json), function(idx, obj) {
               console.log(obj.key);
          });
```

in var JSON there are two sets one [] and second [] which is causing problems to iterate. If it has only one set [] then it works fine.

PHP Code:

```
foreach($str as $key => $keyword){
    $finalData[$key]['key'] = $keyword;
}
print_r(json_encode($finalData));
```

*Note: It may return data with more than 100 of [], but in above example I just mention two.*

Kindly help me out.

Comment: your json string simply is not valid json, since it's just a concatenation of json-arrays. where do you get that string from? that particular code needs to be fixed.

Comment: I added the PHP code in question please review it.

Comment: that is not the complete php-code in question. i would bet that it is somewhere in a loop - would you care showing that part of code, too? also: *why* do you use print_r?

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to create is invalid JSON.

Please wrap your two [] with another [] and comma between both []. Refer code below.

```html
//Sample Code and data

var json = '[[{"key":"amazon"},{"key1":"amazon1"}],[{"key":"amazon"},{"key1":"amazon1"}]]';

console.log(JSON.parse(json));
```

If more help needed, I'm happy to help.

Thanx, Happy Coding.

Comment: just wrapping them does not help, he'd also have to add a comma inbetween, which his sample data does not contain

Comment: $.each(JSON.parse(json), function(idx, obj) {
  console.log(obj.key);
});

idx is a key and obj is current element of each array. 

please print it like console.log(obj) for current object and console.log(key) for current key.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann Surely, I for got to mention in  answer but added it in my code. Thanks for mentioning it.